# JAXBContext load perfectly in server environment but fails in testcase

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, jaxb

In my project i have several maven dependencies. Among one of springContext.xml loads spring web service bean and it loads JAXBContext. It fails with below error-

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name
```

My question is why this code works fine in tomcat server environment and fails in testcase.

Any pointer or hint will be greatly helpful.

**Note**: There is a limitation to change java code or jaxb.properties because this code is auto-generated from xsd files.

Comment: Post your test case code and the full stack trace.

Comment: Testcase code is huge and sensitive also that's wny cannot post stackstrace. Let me try to replicate same issue in a simple project.

Comment: I think the jaxb library used in your project is different in tomcat than in testing. This line could help you determine which jars are used from tomcat, replacing your maven's jaxb dependencies with the corresponding to tomcat should prevent your problem. The line `System.out.println(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException.class.getResource("IllegalAnnotationsException.class"));` This line will show you from which resource (jar file) the class is loaded from.

Comment: @fonkap Thanks for your reply. Tomcat server and testcase both prints out same 'repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.1.11/jaxb-impl-2.1.11.jar'. Testcase was failing during spring container startup. To make it work i disabled bean loading and just printed this statement to check which jar is in preference.

Comment: I'm puzzled. Maybe classpath is different in the two scenarios. Try to create a minimal test project and maybe I could help you more.